# Laravel Missing required parameters for [Route: destroy]

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have create route like below

```
Route::resource('reports/', 'ReportController')->middleware('auth');
```

In route list I have list like below

```
DELETE    | reports/{}             | destroy          | App\Http\Controllers\ReportController@destroy
```

In index.blade.php I have created a delete button like below

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('destroy',['report'=>$report->id])}}" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sute to delete?')">
             @csrf 
             @method("delete")
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
 </form>
```

ReportController Destroy method :

```
public function destroy(Report $report)
{
     //
}
```

But I am getting below error

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: destroy] [URI: reports/{}].
```

Comment: Can you show your `ReportController` please?, where destroy method is referring

Comment: ReportController , destroy method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the / from your route

```
Route::resource('reports/', 'ReportController')->middleware('auth');
```

to

```
Route::resource('reports', 'ReportController')->middleware('auth');
```

Check [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

Your route should look like:

```
DELETE    | reports/{report}             | destroy          | App\Http\Controllers\ReportController@destroy
```

And model Report must be added to RouteServiceProvider.php like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('report', App\Report::class);
```

This is route model binding. Read here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#explicit-binding